# Displaying 3D Model in browser where user can upload custom image for skin

Tags: file-upload, model, 3d, interactive

Forgive my ignorance here, but I'm stumped! I want to be able to have the users of an upcoming site that I'm designing be able to upload an image (based off of a correctly sized template that I will provide) that will be mapped to the surface of a 3D drink can model.

I have basic HTML and CSS coding skills, but HTML5 and CSS3 are a bit of a mystery to me at the moment.

Any ideas?

Comment: what part is troubling you? the image upload, the texture mapping or something else?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! I believe that the texture mapping of the uploaded image as well as how to display an interactive (zoom/rotate) 3D model will be my biggest hurdles. The site will be running off of Drupal 7, so setting up the upload shouldn't be too difficult. Thanks in advance for your insight.